# Visual feedback indicating selected sender address for new compositions in Entourage?

Tags: email, osx-snow-leopard, entourage

I send emails from two addresses using a single Entourage 12.2.4 client.  One of them is a personal work account and one is an administrative account.  It's very easy to send email from the wrong address, and this causes fairly significant problems when it happens.

Do you have any solutions that would make it more obvious which email address is currently selected as the "From:" address in the composition?  Different icons or some sort of color-coding scheme seem like useful ideas, though perhaps too much to expect of the lowly Entourage...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entourage is extremely scriptable, so there's definitely something that can be done. The simplest answer, though, would be to have the two accounts use very different signatures—that should be enough of a visual clue to get your attention.